# Apache VirtualHosts to test multiple redirections

Tags: apache, redirect, mod-rewrite, virtualhost

I'm trying to create a VirtualHost configuration to test how a client handles different redirections to a same server subpath. And also keep it flexible enough to include more status codes (e.g. 307, 308...) in the future.

Also, a desired feature would be to reuse this config regardless of the hostname where it's applied (i.e. redirections are all to the same hostname but in different ports/subpaths). So Apache `Redirects` directive would not probably do the trick.

My first idea was to create separate 2 separate VirtualHosts listening in 2 different interfaces depending on the result HTTP code I wanted to test for and containing `RewriteRule`s for it:

```
Listen 301
Listen 302

<VirtualHost *:301>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [R=301,L]
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:302>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [R=302,L]
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
  [...]
</VirtualHost>
```

Problems is that the port no. (i.e. 301, 302) also ends up being part of the redirected URL so no effective redirect takes place. I even tried out leaving the port outside the regexp's group: `^(.*):302$` without luck.

Comment: It is a bit unclear what you are trying to achieve. Can you give an example of exact url as entered in browser address bar, and the desired destination url.

Comment: @DusanBajic yup; sorry if I was not clear in the first place. Basically, I want `http://<server>:301/whatever` to redirect to `http://<server>/whatever` with a 301 code and `http://<server>:302/whatever` to `http://<server>/whatever` with a permanent redirect (preserving the path and removing the port no.)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
<VirtualHost *:81>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ([^:]*):([0-9]*)$
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,QSA]
</VirtualHost>
```